# Why are OTP password fields masked?

Tags: password, security

If purpose of an OTP (One Time Password) is temporary usage, then what purpose is served by keeping OTP fields masked?

Even if anyone can view that password while user is typing it, IMO there is no harm in it.

Comment: It is probably just because it is easier *not* to remove it. Just creating a an input with type="password" gives the dot masks by default, so the devs probably just didn't bother to go out of their way to remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the inherent inertia of user expectations.  Users have been conditioned to expect their characters to be masked in a real password entry field, so we mask the password to match expectations.